# Java remove child from XML file

Tags: java, xml, xmldom

I would like to delete a child from an XML file and of course save the file after the modification.
Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Customers>
    <Marker>
        <title>ABB EMEA</title>
    </Marker>
    <Marker>
        <title>AllScripts</title>
    </Marker>
    <Marker>
        <title>ARRIS (Motorola)</title>
    </Marker>
    <Marker>
        <title>ARRIS (RWC)</title>
    </Marker>
    <Marker>
        <title>BHS</title>
        <site_location>Weinhammer, Hofhalde, Konstanz, Germany</site_location>
    </Marker>
    <Marker>
        <title>Durst</title>
        <site_location>Brixen, Italy</site_location>
    </Marker>
    <Marker>
        <title>EMEA DEMO</title>
        <site_location>AWS could</site_location>
    </Marker>
    <Marker>
        <title>Harris</title>
    </Marker>

</Customers>
```

I would like to complete remove the child that has the 'title' - 'Durst'.

Here is my code:

```
public static void Rebuild_Cords_XML (File ff)
{
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(ff);

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Marker");
        int x=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++)
        {
            Node nNode = nodes.item(i);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent().equals(("Durst")));
                {

                }
            }
        }


     // write the DOM object to the file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer=null;
                    try {
                        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
                    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(ff);
                    try {
                        transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
                    } catch (TransformerException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
        ;}
}
```

As you can see I am able to detect it manually, but I do not know who to remove it, trying to access a parent node deletes other 'Marker' children but not the required one.

Please assist.

Comment: Do you want to remove `Marker` having `title` equals to Durst? or just title tag?

Comment: I would like to delete the Marker that "title" equals to "Durst".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to delete, so here's both ways.

This will remove the entire marker which contains the title durst:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nodes.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent().equals(("Durst"))) {
                    nNode.getParentNode().removeChild(nNode);
                }
            }
        }
```

This will remove just the title tag in the marker:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nodes.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).getTextContent().equals(("Durst"))) {
                    nNode.removeChild(eElement.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much the first option is the I needed.